# what do you mean by class and its instance ? (java)

Tags: java, class, oop, object, instance

While I was checking some questions I found this question. It asks what is the relationship between a flower and a rose. So the choices were inheritance, class and its instance and interface & its implementation.

Now my problem is the answer should be from what I know is inheritance, but the answer actually was class and its instance. So what I would like to know is what does class and its instance actually mean? From what I know up to now is an instance means an object of a class.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why do you think it would be inheritance? What sort of specializations do you see that would warrant its own definition?

Comment: You seem to understand things pretty well, as far as I can tell. I would have also guessed inheritance ("a rose IS-A flower"), but really I would have looked for option "(D) what kind of a weird analogy is that?" Where did you find this question?

Comment: That is a quite nonsensical question. That "flower and rose" analogy is so far-fetched, I could write a plausible rationale for each of these options being correct.

Comment: @Don'tWasteYourTime "rose extends flower and adds method `prick()`" because of its thorn, for instance. But it also depends whether they meant "a rose in general," or "this particular rose right here." It's a poor analogy, in that it basically forces you to guess what the author of the analogy meant.

Comment: I think this question is opinion-based and open to interpretation.  I'm with the OP here.  A physical object can't ever be just a flower, it must always be something else more specific, so `Flower` is an abstract class.  There are many different (species of) `Rose`, which have the characteristics of a `Flower` and their descriptions would be non-abstract classes, but a particular actual rose you can hold is an instance of one of those subclasses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear what you're asking, not because _you_ are unclear, but because your question is essentially, "what does this unclear question mean?" which is, by definition, unclear. I would either ignore this question or, if it came from a teacher/etc, maybe ask them what they meant (and better yet, try to get them to understand how unclear a question it is).

Comment: Well i found this in a past java paper which was given to me by a lecturer. I will check with him as well about this problem.

Comment: @yshavit, IMHO `Flower` is a poor example of a concrete class. I'd go with interface/implementation. My real question is....

Comment: How was it worded/capped? `Flower` and `rose`? That's implied by naming conventions for Java.

Comment: Stay away from whoever coined that poor/weird/debatable analogy. All 3 answers are arguably correct.

Comment: @Don'tWasteYourTime If someone wrote such an ambiguous question, I certainly wouldn't want to have my answer hinge on something so subtle as their capitalization. ;)

Comment: @yshavit, agreed. However, perhaps the question is purposefully ambiguous as to prompt an extra careful look. I kinda like the idea.My prof.s have always held us accountable for naming conventions and that would stand out as an indicator to me; especially since when considering it leaves only 1 clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A class is like a `template` from which `objects` are created. In the example that you mentioned, the flower could be the class where `rose`, `dandelion`, `lily`, etc could be the instances. For eg,

```
public class Flower {
    private String type;
    ..
    public Flower(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    ..

}
```

And create instances of it as

```
Flower rose = new Flower("rose");
Flower lily = new Flower("lily");
```

This is a viable explanation.

I can see your logical thought process as well. It could have been

```
public class Flower {
    ..
}
```

And subclass like

```
public class Rose extends Flower {
    ..
}
```

and

```
public class Lily extends Flower {
    ..
}
```

But, the subtleties depends on the implementation. It depends on how you see the problem (or rather how the questioner saw the problem). It could as well be `an interface and its implementation`. Again, depends on the implementation.

**Update 1**
There are multiple levels of `inheritance` that you can make out from this problem statement. It all depends on the level of detail you require in your application. If you just want to see any flower just as an entity, you could use `Flower` as a class and different instances of flower as your objects.

Another scenario is when you see a level of detail in your flowers. You want to talk about different types of roses, or different types of lilies, say on their color, size, locations, seasons, etc. In that case, just a `Flower` class is no where sufficient. A `Rose` might have details (`properties`) only relevant to roses, and `Lily` might have some relevant only to lilies. At this point, just a `Flower` is no longer relevant as they give you no important information whatsoever. Now, you could use `Flower` as an `abstract class` or an `interface`, only to denote higher level `properies` or to ensure certain `implementations` are sure to be found. And then create individual classes for each of the inherited flowers like `Rose` and `Lily`.

Hope this clears up the doubt

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This actually cleared my doubts and also since you have shown it in code it made it much easier to understand.

Comment: @Shehan.W Glad it helped. Added some more explanation where the `Flower` class could be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

4) all answers are correct.

**Inheritance** - if there are additional behaviors specific to the rose, which wouldn't characterized any other flower, you will extend the base using inheritance. Another option is to use composition (you at least should favor it).

**Class and its instance** - if there is no added behavior to the rose except its name. You would have a constructor to the flower class, and making a rose would be as simple as instantiating it with its name passed to the constructor.

**Interface & its implementation** - if each type of a flower has a different behavior, but at the same time should follow a determined contract. It is like the first one, except you don't need a base class.

Answer (score 1):

A flower just gives the template the actual *instance* is a `rose`. i.e, *flower* doesn't exist *physically/ virtually*, things which have features of a flower exist and they are called *instances of flower*.

Comment: why not *interface & its implementation.*?

Comment: But `Rose` could just as easily be a class that extends `Flower`.

Comment: @AnkitNigam - Frankly, an interface *forces* its implementation do have some behaviors . It depends on how you see it. If you want tight coupling, then an interface is the answer. Frankly very ambiguous options :)

Answer (score 1):

That's correct that flower->rose would be an example of inheritance.  Flower is more generic, and rose is a specific type of flower.

To keep with the flower example, the concept of a rose would be the class, and individual actual roses would be instances.

A class defines the type, what behavior it has, what types of values it can have as data (or state).  An instance is an object that is a member of that class, with specific values for its state.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `the relationship between flower and the rose` doesn't fit `class and its instance`.

`class and its instance` could fit here if there was a flower class and only a single instance of that class would be a rose. Since there are many roses in the world, it doesn't fit. If you claim that a rose is an instance of a flower that represents the properties of all the roses, and not a single rose, I would argue that there are many types of roses with different properties (for example yellow roses and red roses), so a single instance can't represent all the roses.

I would say that inheritance fits better, since a rose is a kind of a flower.